# DDEV with WSL2: Browser on Windows can't access DDEV project in WSL2

Tags: ddev

Hello after installing Ddev and ddev config under wsl2 Windows my domain is not accessible in the Windows browser.  I installed Mkcert according to the instructions.  Do I have to consider anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say "your domain is not accessible", which can mean a number of things.

- If you're seeing "Unable to look up hostname/domain name" and you're using `*.ddev.site` and not some alternate, then it means you either don't have an internet connection or your DNS server has prohibited DNS Rebinding, which is unusual, but happens often with Fritzbox routers, see https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/troubleshooting/#dns-rebinding-prohibited
- If you're seeing "Unable to connect" in the browser, it probably means an issue with a firewall, so temporarily disable your firewall to see if that's it.

Please see the full set of troubleshooting steps at https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/troubleshooting/#troubleshooting and if you need more help join us for more interactive help in Discord, https://discord.gg/hCZFfAMc5k

Comment: Thank you very much for this information. Now it works without problems

Comment: Glad it's working for you @xmaidem - Please mark this as the accepted answer, and say what worked for you. Was it DNS rebinding that was the problem?

Comment: The missing DNS entry in the Windows hosts file was the problem.